# How to get NSArray from json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a JSON like this

```
{
  accountList: [
    {
      acctId: "",
      acctType: ""
    },
    {
      acctId: "",
      acctType: ""
    }
  ],
  tokenBack: "",
  userId: "",
  verificationCode: ""
}
```

and i want accountList array from that JSON as an array. Any one have solution?

Comment: This is not json, dictionary which represents your dictionary

Comment: Saurabh why people are down-voting your question is because `I have a JSON like this` and the data you have entered in your question is not a json but a dictionary. That is the only reason why people are down-voting your question. Probably you get this output from `NSLog(@"%@", result);` where result is a `NSDictionary` not a `NSString`. Editing your question so that it makes sense. Other wise you can change the title of your question.

Comment: Okay now i know the reason . I will edit my question.Thanks  Inder Kumar Rathore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *accountList = result[@"accountList"];
```

Comment: I used your code but i get compiler error like this :  Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSMutableArray *' . Any idea.

Comment: I have edited my question 5 mins ago please use the latest code